Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class "Auth" does not exist
i am upgrading magento 2.4.6-p3 to 2.4.7-p2
php version 8.2
on frontend iam facing:
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class "Auth" does not exist
Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class "Auth" does not exist
#1 Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getConstructor() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Definition/Runtime.php:50]
#2 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Definition\Runtime->getParameters() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php:100]
#3 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:73]
#4 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get() called at [vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/js/customer-data.phtml:14]
#5 include() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php:67]
#6 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#7 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#8 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#9 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php/Interceptor.php:23]
#10 Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php\Interceptor->render() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php:263]
#11 Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php:293]
#12 Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:1128]
#13 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->Magento\Framework\View\Element\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:1132]
#14 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->_loadCache() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php:676]
#15 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:578]
#16 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:555]
#17 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:510]
#18 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:606]
#19 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:557]
#20 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:510]
#21 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:606]
#22 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:557]
#23 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:510]
#24 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:606]
#25 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:557]
#26 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:510]
#27 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:606]
#28 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:557]
#29 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:510]
#30 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:606]
#31 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:557]
#32 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:510]
#33 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:606]
#34 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:557]
#35 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:510]
#36 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:975]
#37 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getOutput() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#38 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#39 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#40 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:41]
#41 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getOutput() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php:260]
#42 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Layout.php:171]
#43 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#44 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#45 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#46 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php:32]
#47 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:120]
#48 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#49 Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#50 Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/module-application-performance-monitor/Plugin/ApplicationPerformanceMonitor.php:38]
#51 Magento\ApplicationPerformanceMonitor\Plugin\ApplicationPerformanceMonitor->aroundLaunch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#52 Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#53 Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php:23]
#54 Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:264]
#55 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run() called at [pub/index.php:30]

i have run all commands
bin/magento s:up; bin/magento s:d:c; bin/magento s:s:d -f; bin/magento c:f
cammands are excuting properly

It appears to be a bug in magento.
In particular, \Magento\Customer\ViewModel\Customer\Auth class is missing from a block parameter declaration in default.xml in your theme. However, the error is thrown due to the classname being called instead of FQN in vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/js/customer-data.phtml on line 14
$auth = $block->getAuth() ?? ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(Auth::class);

The solution is to add the missing parameter to the block with name "customer.customer.data" making it as following:
<block name="customer.customer.data"  class="Magento\Customer\Block\CustomerData"
               template="Magento_Customer::js/customer-data.phtml">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="auth" xsi:type="object">Magento\Customer\ViewModel\Customer\Auth</argument>
                <argument name="json_serializer" xsi:type="object">Magento\Customer\ViewModel\Customer\JsonSerializer</argument>
                <argument name="cookie_settings" xsi:type="object">Magento\Customer\ViewModel\CookieSettings</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>

